# Centering table within CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center tables within my form and ran into a stumbling block.  I finally have the tables on 1 row, but now need to get them centered without success.  I am not sure whether the problem starts with the fact that I have display: none.  Please help me with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/>

<style type="text/css">

table { border: 1px solid white; width: 100%; }

#tabler1
{
border: 1px solid cyan;
width: 30%;
float: left;
}

#tabler2
{
border: 1px solid yellow;
width: 30%;
float: left;
}

#tabler3
{
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 30%;
float: left;
}

</style>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>

         <form method="POST" action="--WEBBOT-SELF--">

               <table border="1" width="100%" bordercolor="#008000" id="table1">
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <input type=button VALUE="ADVANCED SEARCH">
                     </td>
                  </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td id="tabler1">
                           <table width="100%" name="police_response1" >
                                 <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">Table1</th>
                                 </tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT11</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>

                              <tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT12</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT13</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>
                              </tr> 
                           </table> 
                        </td>

                        <td id="tabler2">
                           <table width="100%" name="police_response1" >
                                 <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">Table2</th>
                                 </tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT21</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>

                              <tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT22</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT23</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>
                              </tr> 
                           </table> 
                        </td>

                        <td id="tabler3">
                           <table width="100%" name="police_response1" >
                                 <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">Table3</th>
                                 </tr>  
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT31</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>

                              <tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT32</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr> 
                                 <td>&nbspFIELD TEXT33</td>
                                 <td>
                                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                                       <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
                                       <option value="ONE">ONE</option>
                                       <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                                       <option>THREE</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </td>
                              </tr> 
                           </table> 
                        </td>
                     </tr>

               </table>

               <div style="clear:both;"></div>

         </form>


</body></html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pepelepe/CyqBn/5/

Comment: Don't use tables for non-tabluar data.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you really want to get centered.

You can center content of those 3 tables with adding `text-align: center;` into the `table` in css style like this:

```
table {
   border: 1px solid white;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

This will center everything inside every of those 3 tables.

Or you can center the whole form - for example put `<div class="master">` just after `<body>` tag and `</div>` after the `</form>` tag. Then into your stylesheet put this:

```
.master {
   margin: 0px auto;
}
```

This should center the form itself in the document.

Comment: that centers the contents, I want to center the table so that all 3 are spaced apart evenly.  The contents I will probably want either left, or the first column right and the second column left, but that I will worry after I get them spaced apart.

Comment: In that case, put `margin: 10px;` into every `#tabler` and adjust the pixels (10 is maybe too litle for you, try more...). Or just do `#tabler1, #tabler2, #tabler3 {margin: 10px;}` and you will get that margin for all of them (thats a shorter notation).

Comment: yes, that works for 30% and 45%, but if I change those numbers they are not properly spaced.  I think I need margin:0 auto; somewhere to make it evenly, but can't find where to put it.